# TCL: get the class name of an object?

Tags: tcl, incr-tcl

How to get class name of itcl object or check if the object exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using info class e.g.

```
objName info class
```

See also http://wiki.tcl.tk/12629 for more information on checking existence using **itcl::is**

```
itcl::is object objName
```